# Reading a file using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm having some trouble understanding how Java uses Scanner to read lines from a file and was hoping to get some clarification after days of confusion.

I have a .txt file with one line that contains a name and then 5 doubles. I'm trying to figure out how I can assign each of those to a variable inside a loop so I can work with the data. My goal is to actually take the data from these lines and pass them as parameters to another method for validation, so if there's an easier way to do that, I'm all ears. I feel like I can't find a way to just iterate over each thing inside the nextLine, just over the entire line itself. I'm trying to do this without using an array, here's the relevant code snippet I have right now.

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        String line = "";
        accumulator++;
        Scanner split = new Scanner(inputFile.nextLine());

       while (split.hasNext()) 
       {

       }



        stockName = inputFile.next();
        shares = inputFile.nextDouble();
        purchasePrice = inputFile.nextDouble();
        purchaseCommission = inputFile.nextDouble();
        salesPrice = inputFile.nextDouble();
        salesCommission = inputFile.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(stockName);
        System.out.println(shares);
        System.out.println(purchasePrice);
        System.out.println(purchaseCommission);
        System.out.println(salesPrice);
        System.out.println(salesCommission);


        System.out.print(line);
        System.out.println("");
        // checkValidity(line);
    }
```

I'm having a hard time asking and articulating what I don't know, so any and all help is greatly appreciated... I've literally been working on this for three days and I'm at a total wall.

EDIT:

The layout of the text file looks like this

```
DELL: Dell Inc
125 25.567  0.025   28.735  0.025
MSFT: Microsoft
34.1    -15.75  0.012   15.90   0.013
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You need to just remove the line:

```
while (split.hasNext()) 
{

}
```

This consumes all the elements given to split. You need to assign this to all the elements like `stock`, `salesPrice` etc.

So, the new snippet inside the outer while loop is

```
    stockName = inputFile.nextLine();
    Scanner split = new Scanner(inputFile.nextLine());        

    shares = split.nextDouble();
    purchasePrice = split.nextDouble();
    purchaseCommission = split.nextDouble();
    salesPrice = split.nextDouble();
    salesCommission = split.nextDouble();
```

Since, you are reading line by line, also make sure the outer while loop looks like:

```
while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {

}
```

Comment: The file is actually laid out so that the name is on one line and the next line is all the data I need. I tried switching stockName to split.nextLine() but then it throws an error about the next line (shares) for NoSuchElementException. Any idea why? Shouldn't stockName just consume the whole line and then move to the next line automatically?